# Dynamic php: loading var with string from database does not work

Tags: php, string, image, base64

I have this select query:

```
$sql = "SELECT id,nombre,
                CAST(archivo as VARCHAR(MAX)) as archivo,
                extension 
        from documents 
        WHERE id= :id";            

$valores=array(':id' => $id );
```

this returns a php object that contents:

```
object(Documentacion)[7]
  private 'id' => string '136' (length=3)
  private 'nombre' => string 'adjunto_dni' (length=11)
  private 'archivo' => string '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' (length=46152)
  private 'extension' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
```

I want to show this image in an `<img>` tag and for this I use this (which does not work):

```
$ruta_img = "data:image/jpeg;base64,".$doc->archivo;
    echo "<img src='{$ruta_img}' alt=''>";
```

but if I set the the var "ruta_img" manually like this:

```
$ruta_img = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQA...';
```

the image shows fine.

Does somebody know why it works if I load the var with the string manually, and if I load dynamically it doesn't? To make sure that the dynamic string is the same as the string loaded manually I have do a echo and the strings are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `archivo` variable in the `Documentacion` object is marked `private`.

Make it as `public` instead of `private` and you code will work fine.